# Pole target drags behind IK

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

I'm learning how to rig and one of the problems I have is trying to have the pole target bone move with the leg to keep the direction it's pointing at the same.

I know I could parent the pole to the IK bone but that seems to move the bone quite a lot.

So the current system I have for the pole is based on from this YouTube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suP14lYWpN8

and while it seems to work nicely, the only problem with it is that the pole bones visibly drag behind the rest of the skeleton which doesn't look good when animated.

Is there any way to reduce or get rid off this drag? Or is there a better way to go about this?

(The blue & red circles are the pole target bones here on the rig)
[image]

Blender 2.8 file

[image]